# Passwordless and mongostore

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, npm-install, password-less

I clone a github repo( https://github.com/rbudiharso/smsauth-example ) for passwordless example, but when I try to do a npm install from package.json

ERR starts to pop up with the message below.

One of the error message points out that `node-gyp rebuild` which i have no idea.

Another error message points out `problem with bcrypt`.

The module that I tried to install but failed was `passwordless-mongostore` (available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passwordless-mongostore))

So when I tried to install `node-gyp`, the below error log still exist.

```
WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:330:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:70:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:82:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:91:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-c9
gyp ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passwordless-mongostore/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/npm-debug.log
```

so I just want to install and run the project before writing everything out, can someone assist one this?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: "Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable." Do you have Python installed?

Comment: nope. This is a nodeJS module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though [`paswordless-mongostore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passwordless-mongostore) is an NPM module it has Python dependencies. It depends directly on [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), which depends both directly and indirectly on [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

> `node-gyp` is a cross-platform command-line tool written in Node.js for compiling native addon modules for Node.js. It bundles the [gyp](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/) project used by the Chromium team and takes away the pain of dealing with the various differences in build platforms.

`gyp` itself is [written in Python](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp/+/master), and `node-gyp` includes [Python code](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/tree/master/gyp/pylib/gyp) directly. The error you are seeing comes from its [`configure.js` file and is triggered when Python is not found](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/77383ddd85744a4408eac2c6d684c30284ca96dd/lib/configure.js#L448-L451).

You have at least two options:

- **Install Python.**

  Depending on your environment this could range from a simple one-line command to completely infeasible.
- **Use a different library**, e.g. [`passwordless-mongostore-bcrypt-node`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passwordless-mongostore-bcrypt-node).

  The `passwordless-mongostore` README includes this suggestion:

  > Tokens are stored in a MongoDB database and are hashed and salted using [bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/). *If you have trouble installing bcrypt (esp. on Windows) you could also consider using the [slower but pure-JS version](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passwordless-mongostore-bcrypt-node) of MongoStore.*